# Alternative Grover's Diffuse Operator

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I was wondering if there is any good references where I could read to understand the construction of Unitary Operators such as the Diffuse Operator in Grover's Algorithm.

I am looking to build my own set of unitary operators with the objective of boosting the amplitude of specific quantum states for which there is no access to oracles to perform the phase flip prior to the inversion about the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the decomposition of Grover's diffusion algorithm into simple gates : [How can you decompose Grover's diffusion operator into gates?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13313/8746).

However, when you want to increase the amplitude of states, you should look into amplitude amplification. You could start looking at :  [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_amplification).

However, you will always require a Hermitian Projector operator or an oracle function.